# How does the surface of a sphere break the parallel postulate?

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I'm currently studying non-Euclidean geometry and recently learned that a sphere is in 3-dimensional Euclidean space, but its surface is not.

According to my findings, non-Euclidean spaces are "spaces where the parallel postulate does not hold." ([History of manifolds and varieties - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_manifolds_and_varieties)) meaning that if there was a line and we were to draw two lines such that the inner angles are less than 90 degrees, the two lines would never meet. Please correct me if I'm understanding this fundamentally incorrectly.

If I have understood it correctly, then does the surface of a sphere satisfy this postulate? If I were to draw a line on the surface of a sphere and draw two lines such that the inner angle they make with the first line is less than 90 degrees, I'm pretty sure that they would meet somewhere on the surface.

Would anyone be kind enough to help me understand this concept? Thanks in advance.

P.S., I've taken a look at this Math Stack Exchange question: [Spherical Geometry and Playfair's Axiom](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322272/spherical-geometry-and-playfairs-axiom) but it didn't help so much.

Comment: well, any two lines on the surface of a sphere meet...

Comment: Yes, that's kind of the motivation for my question. If the surface of a sphere is in non-Euclidean space, shouldn't it cause the parallel postulate to fail?

Comment: The parallel postulate states that through any given point not on a line there passes exactly one line parallel to that line in the same plane, but parallel lines do not exist on a sphere. Hence, it is not a Euclidean space

Comment: Does this figure help ?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_(geometry)#/media/File:SphereParallel.png

Comment: People in the comments are talking about [Playfair's axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair%27s_axiom), which is not exactly the same as [Euclid's original parallel postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate).

Comment: In Euclidean geometry, the sum of the three angles of a triangle is $2\pi$.  In hyperbolic geometry, less than $2\pi$.  In elliptic geometry (much like the surface of a sphere), greater than $2\pi$.

Comment: @LukasRollier : not sure what is meant by "any two lines on the surface of a sphere meet.", latitudes don't cross each other.

Comment: Any two geodesics I mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is that line segments on the surface of a sphere do not work the same way as the Euclidean metric in space.  For instance, [the shortest distance along the surface from Singapore to San Francisco passes through Tokyo](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=SFO-NRT-SIN,SFO-HKG-SIN), which is not what you would expect at all from looking at the Pacific Ocean on a rectangular map.

So lines on a sphere are "great circles", which represent circles in space whose center is the center of the sphere.  Thinking of the globe again, all longitudinal lines are great circles, but the Equator is the only latitudinal line that is a great circle.  Based on that definition of lines in the sphere, it is not hard to convince yourself that any two distinct lines on a sphere must intersect in two places.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The concept of great circles was actually something that I was wondering about. I've read somewhere that "straight lines in spheres are great circles" or something along those lines. What exactly makes this true? Aren't small circles also straight lines?

Comment: @Seankala Understanding great circles is one of those things where a year of thinking about it isn't as valuable as thirty seconds with a globe and a piece of string.  It will give you a firm conviction that small circles don't measure the shortest distance between two points on the surface of a sphere.

Comment: Ah I think I've got it. I hadn't kept in mind that a line is the shortest distance between two points. And like you said, in a sphere the distance between two points is longer with small circles than with that of great circles. Thanks.